# Adding elements with javascript to DIV (height 100%) doesn't change the div's height?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a DIV element with one more DIV inside as last elements of my website inside body. I would like to stretch it's height to 100% and give it some background color (works fine so far) but I have a button on website which adds a table to the inner DIV.

Problem: when I keep adding a few of these tables they overflow from the div - div's colored background doesn't stretch with it's content (fiddle below demonstrates my problem, simply click on proceed a few times and you will see that the text goes out of the blue area but the blue area doesn't strech any further).

Is there a way how to do this?

Thank you very much.

HTML code

```
<div id="button">
proceed
</div>
<div id="box">
  <div id="results">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS code

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

#box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #3498eb;
}

#clearDiv {
  clear: both;
}
```

Javascript code

```
var button = document.getElementById('button');
button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var results = document.getElementById('results');

  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    var table = document.createElement('table');
    var row = document.createElement('tr');
    var cell1 = document.createElement('td');
    var cell2 = document.createElement('td');
    results.appendChild(table);
    table.appendChild(row);
    row.appendChild(cell1);
    row.appendChild(cell2);
    cell1.innerHTML = 'test1';
    cell2.innerHTML = 'test2';
  }

  console.log('done');
}, false);
```

[fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/0hoykhgk/6/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [min-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height) instead of `height`. `height` tells the element stay at a particular height. `min-height` on the other hand sets the minimum height an element can be and will allow it to expand when needed.

```
#box {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: #3498eb;
}
```

Demo

```js
var button = document.getElementById('button');
button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
 var results = document.getElementById('results');
 
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    var table = document.createElement('table');
    var row = document.createElement('tr');
    var cell1 = document.createElement('td');
    var cell2 = document.createElement('td');
    results.appendChild(table);
    table.appendChild(row);
    row.appendChild(cell1);
    row.appendChild(cell2);
    cell1.innerHTML = 'test1';
    cell2.innerHTML = 'test2';
  }

  console.log('done');
}, false);
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

#box {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: #3498eb;
}

#clearDiv {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="button">
proceed
</div>
<div id="box">
  <div id="results">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your CSS:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
}
#box {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: #3498eb;
  overflow: auto;
}
#results {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/mw1w4ykb/

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to simply change:

```
#box {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: #3498eb;
}
```

Comment: `overflow-y` is **NOT** standardized contrary to popular belief. It's also not supported in Firefox for that reason.